# SQL to show lower limit provided the upper limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample dataset like this:

| rank | Upper_limit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.11 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4.5 |
| 4 | 8.1 |
| 5 | 9.7 |

My desired output is this

| rank | Lower_limit | Upper_limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2.11 |
| 2 | 2.11 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 4.5 |
| 4 | 4.5 | 8.1 |
| 5 | 8.1 | 9.7 |

How can I achieve it using T-SQL?

Comment: Hint: `LAG()`, `ISNULL()`.

Comment: It's helpful if you can explain your desire, i.e. how you want the `Lower_limit` and `Upper_limit` divined from the sample dataset. We shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `LAG()` analytic function we can try:

```sql
SELECT [rank],
       LAG(Upper_limit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [rank]) AS Lower_limit,
       Upper_limit
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY [rank];
```

Comment: @ARC You were correct, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

USING [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function, this can be possible:

```
CREATE TABLE RankTable ([Rank] INT, Upper_Limit DECIMAL (8,2));

INSERT INTO RankTable ([Rank], Upper_Limit)
SELECT 1, 2.11 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3    UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4.5  UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 8.1  UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 9.7 ;

SELECT [Rank], 
       ISNULL(LAG(Upper_Limit, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Rank]), 0) AS Lower_Limit, 
       Upper_Limit
FROM RankTable
```

Working Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=395b137d2301538946e5dbb397caea90